# Resharper not debugging MSTest tests

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, resharper, mstest

I'm using Resharper Ultimate 2017.3.1

When I try to debug a unit tests

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow("bla", "blub")]
public void Test_When_Then() { ... }
```

Then the test stops debugging, changes to state `inconclusive` and the following error is shown in the resharper test explorer window:

> 2018.01.17 13:02:20.367   ERROR Transition failed: Transition from state  on event . Cause:
>   System.ArgumentException: There should be at least one test in the
>   test run. Parametername: tests --->
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException: There should be at least one test
>   in the test run. Parametername: tests Server stack trace: at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message) Exception rethrown at [0]: at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Core.ITestExecutorService.StartTestRun(IEnumerable`1
>   tests, String testRunSettings, TestExecutionContext executionContext,
>   String dataCollectorServiceUri) at
>   JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTesting.MSTest.Provider.Execution.Wcf.TestExecutorServiceProxy.StartTestRun(IEnumerable`1
>   tests, String testRunSettings, TestExecutionContext executionContext,
>   String dataCollectorServiceUri) --- End of inner exception stack trace
>   --- at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTesting.MSTest.Provider.Execution.Wcf.TestExecutorServiceProxy.StartTestRun(IEnumerable`1
>   tests, String testRunSettings, TestExecutionContext executionContext,
>   String dataCollectorServiceUri) at
>   JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTesting.MSTest.Provider.Execution.MsTestExecutionProtocol.StartTestRun()
>   at
>   Appccelerate.StateMachine.Machine.ActionHolders.ArgumentLessActionHolder.Execute(Object
>   argument) in
>   C:\projects\appccelerate\repos\statemachine\source\Appccelerate.StateMachine\Machine\ActionHolders\ArgumentLessActionHolder.cs:line
>   37 at
>   Appccelerate.StateMachine.Machine.States.State`2.ExecuteEntryAction(IActionHolder
>   actionHolder, ITransitionContext`2 context) in
>   C:\projects\appccelerate\repos\statemachine\source\Appccelerate.StateMachine\Machine\States\State.cs:line
>   340
>
> --- EXCEPTION #1/1 [LoggerException] Message = “   Transition failed: Transition from state  on event .
>   Cause: System.ArgumentException: There should be at least one test in
>   the test run.   Parametername: tests --->
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException: There should be at least one test
>   in the test run.   Parametername: tests
>        Server stack trace: 
>        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
>        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>        Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>        at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>        at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)
>        at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Core.ITestExecutorService.StartTestRun(IEnumerable`1
>   tests, String testRunSettings, TestExecutionContext executionContext,
>   String dataCollectorServiceUri)
>        at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTesting.MSTest.Provider.Execution.Wcf.TestExecutorServiceProxy.StartTestRun(IEnumerable`1
>   tests, String testRunSettings, TestExecutionContext executionContext,
>   String dataCollectorServiceUri)
>        --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>        at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTesting.MSTest.Provider.Execution.Wcf.TestExecutorServiceProxy.StartTestRun(IEnumerable`1
>   tests, String testRunSettings, TestExecutionContext executionContext,
>   String dataCollectorServiceUri)
>        at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTesting.MSTest.Provider.Execution.MsTestExecutionProtocol.StartTestRun()
>        at Appccelerate.StateMachine.Machine.ActionHolders.ArgumentLessActionHolder.Execute(Object
>   argument) in
>   C:\projects\appccelerate\repos\statemachine\source\Appccelerate.StateMachine\Machine\ActionHolders\ArgumentLessActionHolder.cs:line
>   37
>        at Appccelerate.StateMachine.Machine.States.State`2.ExecuteEntryAction(IActionHolder
>   actionHolder, ITransitionContext`2 context) in
>   C:\projects\appccelerate\repos\statemachine\source\Appccelerate.StateMachine\Machine\States\State.cs:line
>   340 ” ExceptionPath = Root ClassName = JetBrains.Util.LoggerException
>   HResult = COR_E_APPLICATION=80131600 StackTraceString = “   at
>   JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTesting.MSTest.Provider.Execution.MsTestExecutionProtocol.<.ctor>b__10(Object
>   sender, TransitionExceptionEventArgs`2 args)
>        at Appccelerate.StateMachine.Machine.StateMachine`2.RaiseEvent[T](EventHandler`1
>   eventHandler, T arguments, ITransitionContext`2 context, Boolean
>   raiseEventOnException) in
>   C:\projects\appccelerate\repos\statemachine\source\Appccelerate.StateMachine\Machine\StateMachine.cs:line
>   404
>        at Appccelerate.StateMachine.Machine.StateMachine`2.OnExceptionThrown(ITransitionContext`2
>   context, Exception exception) in
>   C:\projects\appccelerate\repos\statemachine\source\Appccelerate.StateMachine\Machine\StateMachine.cs:line
>   260
>        at Appccelerate.StateMachine.Machine.Contexts.TransitionContext`2.OnExceptionThrown(Exception
>   exception) in
>   C:\projects\appccelerate\repos\statemachine\source\Appccelerate.StateMachine\Machine\Contexts\TransitionContext.cs:line
>   74
>        at Appccelerate.StateMachine.Machine.States.State`2.HandleException(Exception
>   exception, ITransitionContext`2 context) in
>   C:\projects\appccelerate\repos\statemachine\source\Appccelerate.StateMachine\Machine\States\State.cs:line
>   307
>        at Appccelerate.StateMachine.Machine.States.State`2.HandleEntryActionException(ITransitionContext`2
>   context, Exception exception) in
>   C:\projects\appccelerate\repos\statemachine\source\Appccelerate.StateMachine\Machine\States\State.cs:line
>   357
>        at Appccelerate.StateMachine.Machine.States.State`2.ExecuteEntryAction(IActionHolder
>   actionHolder, ITransitionContext`2 context) in
>   C:\projects\appccelerate\repos\statemachine\source\Appccelerate.StateMachine\Machine\States\State.cs:line
>   345
>        at Appccelerate.StateMachine.Machine.States.State`2.ExecuteEntryActions(ITransitionContext`2
>   context) in
>   C:\projects\appccelerate\repos\statemachine\source\Appccelerate.StateMachine\Machine\States\State.cs:line
>   330
>        at Appccelerate.StateMachine.Machine.States.State`2.Entry(ITransitionContext`2
>   context) in
>   C:\projects\appccelerate\repos\statemachine\source\Appccelerate.StateMachine\Machine\States\State.cs:line
>   247
>        at Appccelerate.StateMachine.Machine.States.State`2.EnterShallow(ITransitionContext`2
>   context) in
>   C:\projects\appccelerate\repos\statemachine\source\Appccelerate.StateMachine\Machine\States\State.cs:line
>   285
>        at Appccelerate.StateMachine.Machine.States.State`2.EnterHistoryNone(ITransitionContext`2
>   context) in
>   C:\projects\appccelerate\repos\statemachine\source\Appccelerate.StateMachine\Machine\States\State.cs:line
>   429
>        at Appccelerate.StateMachine.Machine.States.State`2.EnterByHistory(ITransitionContext`2
>   context) in
>   C:\projects\appccelerate\repos\statemachine\source\Appccelerate.StateMachine\Machine\States\State.cs:line
>   263
>        at Appccelerate.StateMachine.Machine.Transitions.Transition`2.Fire(ITransitionContext`2
>   context) in
>   C:\projects\appccelerate\repos\statemachine\source\Appccelerate.StateMachine\Machine\Transitions\Transition.cs:line
>   87
>        at Appccelerate.StateMachine.Machine.States.State`2.Fire(ITransitionContext`2
>   context) in
>   C:\projects\appccelerate\repos\statemachine\source\Appccelerate.StateMachine\Machine\States\State.cs:line
>   222
>        at Appccelerate.StateMachine.Machine.StateMachine`2.Fire(TEvent eventId, Object eventArgument) in
>   C:\projects\appccelerate\repos\statemachine\source\Appccelerate.StateMachine\Machine\StateMachine.cs:line
>   230
>        at Appccelerate.StateMachine.PassiveStateMachine`2.ProcessQueuedEvents()
>   in
>   C:\projects\appccelerate\repos\statemachine\source\Appccelerate.StateMachine\PassiveStateMachine.cs:line
>   339
>        at Appccelerate.StateMachine.PassiveStateMachine`2.Execute() in C:\projects\appccelerate\repos\statemachine\source\Appccelerate.StateMachine\PassiveStateMachine.cs:line
>   324
>        at Appccelerate.StateMachine.PassiveStateMachine`2.Fire(TEvent eventId, Object eventArgument) in
>   C:\projects\appccelerate\repos\statemachine\source\Appccelerate.StateMachine\PassiveStateMachine.cs:line
>   177
>        at Appccelerate.StateMachine.PassiveStateMachine`2.Fire(TEvent eventId) in
>   C:\projects\appccelerate\repos\statemachine\source\Appccelerate.StateMachine\PassiveStateMachine.cs:line
>   163
>        at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTesting.MSTest.Provider.Execution.Wcf.TestExecutorServiceClient.TestConnection(IEnumerable`1
>   dummyTestResults)
>        at SyncInvokeTestConnection(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
>        at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
>        at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)
>        at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)
>        at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)
>        at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)
>        at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)
>        at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)
>        at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)
>        at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)
>        at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)
>        at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
>        at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(RequestContext
>   request, Boolean cleanThread, OperationContext
>   currentOperationContext)
>        at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(RequestContext
>   request, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
>        at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult
>   result)
>        at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.OnAsyncReceiveComplete(IAsyncResult
>   result)
>        at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult
>   result)
>        at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
>        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportDuplexSessionChannel.TryReceiveAsyncResult.OnReceive(IAsyncResult
>   result)
>        at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult
>   result)
>        at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
>        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SynchronizedMessageSource.ReceiveAsyncResult.OnReceiveComplete(Object
>   state)
>        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.OnAsyncReadComplete(Object
>   state)
>        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.OnRead(IAsyncResult
>   result)
>        at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult
>   result)
>        at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
>        at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken)
>        at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ProcessFrameBody(Int32 readBytes, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count,
>   AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>        at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ReadCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest
>   asyncRequest)
>        at System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest.CompleteRequest(Int32 result)
>        at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.CheckCompletionBeforeNextRead(Int32 bytes)
>        at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult transportResult)
>        at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
>        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.IOAsyncResult.OnAsyncIOComplete(Object
>   state)
>        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.PipeConnection.OnAsyncReadComplete(Boolean
>   haveResult, Int32 error, Int32 numBytes)
>        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.OverlappedContext.CompleteCallback(UInt32
>   error, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
>        at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32
>   error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
>        at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32
>   errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP) ”

Has anyone had this error too and knows how to fix it so that I can debug my unit tests again?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this error when updating ReSharper, it turned out to be a problem with the referenced NuGet packages related to Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform were outdated.

Create a new test project and compare the versions of these assemblies which will be added automatically when the project is created.

Using version 14.0.0.1 is working for me for the following assemblies:

[image: References]

- ReSharper 2017.3.1
- VS 2017 15.5.3